# PHP Removing by reference

Tags: php, unset, stdclass

I'm trying to remove stdClass property by reference. Because I don't know how deeply the property is nested, a reference is made in the loop. But the unset method does not remove variables by reference. How can I resolve it without just setting a null value?

```
<?php
$data = new stdClass();
$data->foo = new stdClass();
$data->foo->bar = 'value';

$pathToRemove = 'foo.bar';

$dataReference = &$data;
foreach (explode('.', $pathToRemove) as $field) {
    $dataReference = &$dataReference->$field;
}
unset($dataReference);

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: yes you can use null or `unset` and if there is no variable pointing to same reference it will be deleted, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php also you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

Comment: This is because if you use a reference then `unset` will release the reference. In your example: do you want to remove `bar`, or all incl. `foo` ?

Comment: I want to remove only bar field. The example is simplified, I have many different fields. I'd like to remove the field completely, setting it to null will still display it.

Comment: Then the answer from @Barmar is what you need. Note: he unset `$referenceVar->$property`. So not on the reference it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over all the elements except the last. Then use the last element as the field to delete.

```
$pathArray = explode('.', $pathToRemove);
$lastField = array_pop($pathArray);
$dataReference = &$data;
foreach ($pathArray as $field) {
    $dataReference = &$dataReference->{$field};
}
unset($dataReference->{$lastField});
unset($dataReference); // don't need the reference variable any more
```

Comment: `$path_array`  should be `$pathArray`?

Comment: Works. Would suggest `unset($dataReference);` at the end to release the reference (to not accidentally change `$data` later on). And i suggest `$dataReference->{$lastField}` (use of `{}`).